# Unwanted systray icons

Tags: unity, indicator

Is there any way to manage the icons in your systray? It's not highly important, but it annoys me having icons there that I don't want or use. It seems a little strange that it's so easy to customise just about everything else, but I can't for the life of me find a way to edit the systray. Maybe I'm just missing something?

If there are specific ways of getting rid of each one, the I'd like to remove the Ubuntu One icon, the mail icon, and possibly the icon that says En1, and allows you to choose between UK and US English, unless that is important and I haven't realised it. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing the Mail icon, open **Terminal** and copy & paste the following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove indicator-messages
```

For the Keyboard Layout, click on it and de-select **Show Current Input Source In The Menu Bar**

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Annoying that they don't have a manager for it.